# RSelenium issue after ChromeDriver version 114

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I am having problems with RSelenium after the changes in ChromeDriver.

As you might have noticed, ChromeDriver had a change after version 114. It become something like "Chrome for Testing", as you can see the change at the download page also:
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

In the new ChromeDriver versions, name of the exe file has been changed. It's "chrome.exe" , while it was "chromedriver.exe" in the past versions. That's why rsDriver() function cannot find the ChromeDriver. So, in the new chromedriver folder I download, I have renamed the "chrome.exe" to "chromedriver.exe".

`rs_driver_object <- rsDriver(browser="chrome", chromever="118.0.5993.70", port = free_port(), verbose=T)`

It opens a browser window. But my r session hangs on  `[1] "Connecting to remote server"` about 1 or half a minute and then gives this error:

```
Selenium message:Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-4Q2RK2L2', ip: '192.168.0.3', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_381'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

**Could not open chrome browser.**
Client error message:
     Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
Check server log for further details.
```

I guess the problem occurs from this: The new opened browser window is not exactly a Chrome window. In the task manager it is named as "Google Chrome For Testing". And when I hover to the icon of this app at the desktop toolbar , it says "Chromium". So I guess it thinks that it couldn't open the Chrome browser , although it's open.

PS: I can not use a Firefox browser or a headless Chrome. I'm getting help of a specific Chrome extension in my app and this extension does not exist in other browsers.

Additional notes:

I have read the codes of RSelenium library, and run those codes to find the reason of the error.

```
    selServ <- wdman::selenium(
        port = 4567L,
        verbose = TRUE,
        version = "latest",
        chromever = "118.0.5993.70",
        geckover = "latest",
        iedrver = NULL,
        phantomver = "2.1.1",
        check = TRUE
    )
```

Everything is ok here. So the problem is not related with the wdman part.

```
    remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = browser, port = 4567L)
    remDr$version <- "118.0.5993.70"
```

This also looks fine but the problem comes from here.

```
csEnv <- new.env()
    csEnv[["server"]] <- selServ
    csEnv[["client"]] <- remDr
    clean <- function(e) {
        chk <- suppressMessages(
            tryCatch(e[["client"]]$close(), error = function(e) e)
        )
        e[["server"]]$stop()
    }
    reg.finalizer(csEnv, clean)
    class(csEnv) <- c("rsClientServer", class(csEnv))
```

When I run `csEnv[["client"]]$open()` opens the browser, but the same error happens and getting exact same error messages. So the problem is somewhere in the functions RSelenium uses in the open() function. But I couldn't succeed to call those functions. At least, the error is stuck into a little area.

### Summary

I have tried

```
rD <- rsDriver(browser="chrome", chromever="118.0.5993.70",  port = free_port() , verbose=T)
```

and

```
rD<-remoteDriver(port=4576L, browserName='chrome',  extraCapabilities = cprof)
rD$open()
```

Although it opens the window of the browser, it gives an error that it couldn't open Chrome browser, and says timed out waiting for driver server to start.